# How to get today's events from Google Calendar (API) using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I'm new to Google Calendar APIs and what I'm trying to do is to display today's events from a public Google Calendar using JavaScript.

I've found this [resource](http://gdata-javascript-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/calendar/simple_sample/simple_sample.html)<sub>(dead link)</sub>, but I can't figure it out how to modify it so that it will output only today's events.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question. Also do bear in mind you can accept your own answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the API: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/apps-script

You can set the start-min and start-max parameters.

Comment: Yes, this is what I end up doing. See the **Edit** from my question.

Comment: Dead link :(. I used https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/apps-script

Answer (score -2):

AuthSub proxy authentication is used by web applications which need to authenticate their users to Google accounts. The website operator does not need access to the username and password for the calendar user - only special AuthSub tokens are required. Please see the AuthSub documentation for more detailed information.

When a user first visits your application, they have not yet been authenticated. In this case, you need to print some text and a link directing the user to Google to authenticate your request for access to their calendar. The Python Google Data API client library provides a function to generate this URL from the CalendarService class. The code below sets up a link to the AuthSubRequest page.